# What happens with lazily loaded entities after em.close()?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have some entities and lazily loaded references.

```
EntityA {

@ManyToMany
private List<EntityB> bs;

}

EntityB {

@ManyToMany
private List<EntityA> as;

}
```

I am wondering if it is save to access those lazy-collections outside the persistence context (PC) **if they have been loaded inside the PC before?**
E.g.

```
// put into PC
a = em.merge(a);
// trigger lazy loading
a.bs.size();
em.close();
// access outside PC
a.bs.size();
```

I made a small test with EclipseLink and this seems to work. But I am not sure if that is because:

1. The lazy-Lists are stored using weak references and are accessible for now but may be GCed at some point,
2. The lazy-lists are fetched from the db even though the entity is not in the PC (for whatever reason),
3. The lazy-Lists are initiated and will be accessible anytime, even if the database will be closed.

Answer (score 3):

EclipseLink keeps a connection to the datastore while the EMF is open, even when the EM is closed, so will still be able to load lazy fields until you close the EMF. This is arguably against the JPA spec, and many argue it as an anti-pattern.

Other JPA providers will **not** do it like this, so, if you want to be 100% JPA standard compliant, you should not rely on it and make sure you load lazy fields before EM close. If a field has not been loaded by EM close then accessing it will likely throw an exception (depends on the JPA provider).

Comment: This might sound stupid, but once initialized it is a 'collection like any other', right? No weak references, proxies or any other 'magic' going on in the background?

Comment: No idea. I don't use EclipseLink. Why not try it, and print out the class of the Collection field?

Comment: Yes, once fetched, a reference is there in the entity just like any other. The context is only needed if it wasn’t fetched

Comment: Ive run a test, and the instance of the list is `IndirectList` even after `em.close()`. Is this because EclipseLink supports Lazy Fetching outside of a transaction?

Comment: This is also the case if the List is annotated with `FetchType.EAGER`.